# SplendidCRM project couldn't be run from visual studio

Tags: asp.net

I have installed SplendidCRM Community edition , and when i have opened the solution in visual studio  to run the code i faced the following error

```
Error   240 The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SplendidCRMWeb Site\Calendar\DayGrid.ascx.cs 25  18  SplendidTest
```

How can I solve this error ? Please help me since i am new in SplendidCRM ..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We provide CSPROJ files with the application.  You must open the appropriate project file for your version of Visual Studio.  SplendidCRM7_VS2010 for Visual Studio 2010, for example.  If you have a newer version of Visual Studio, just open the newest project file and Visual Studio will convert appropriately.